# Insert Image in Center of Table

Tags: html

I Wonder if anyone can help me. I just started working with CSS and was looking to replicated one of the pages of a newsletter I saw. My main problem is that I can't seem to be able to insert the arrow image made with lots of people into the center of the page.

I have used lots of tables and inserting the image in a row breaks the page.
Would really appreciate your help.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>


<table style="border: 1px solid #223e86;" border="0" width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

  <tr>
  ---------------------INSERT IMAGE IN THE CENTER OF ONE COLUMN ROW------------------
  </tr>

<tr>
  <td style="padding-left: 12px; font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
 LOT is proud to be launching <i>LOT
Careers</i>. This tailor-made online portal
will provide members and trainees with
free access to browse and apply for the
largest single source of LOT,
jobs worldwide.
<p />
As an LOT member you will be
able to search job vacancies relevant
to your qualification, geographical
location and sector. The site will also
offer comprehensive guidance, advice
and developments in the financial
recruitment process and with your career
management.</td>

<td>
<H2 style="font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 20px; text-transform:uppercase; color: #B00000; font-weight:bold;">FEATURES:</H2>
<pre style="font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
* Expert careers content (news, videos, 
  articles, advice and information) 
* Find out about the recruitment market 
  in a destination of your choice
* Search vacancies by job title, skills 
  required, region or LOT status
* Sign up to receive tailored email alerts
  when relevant jobs are posted
* Upload and store your CV
* Apply for jobs with one click
* Debate the latest topics in the 
  Think Tank with other professionals 
  in the industry
</pre></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
 &nbsp; 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="padding-left: 12px; font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
 <i>LOT Careers</i> will also provide access to
thousands of LOT qualified jobseekers
for any organisation looking for the best
new talent.
  </td>

  <td style="padding-right: 12px; font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; text-transform:uppercase; color: #B00000; font-weight:bold;">
 Pre-register today at www.oursite.com
 whether you’re interested in making
your next career move, or want to recruit
your next employee
  </td>
</tr>






<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<!--third one-->

<tr>
<td>



</td>
</tr>
<!--
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<!--forth one-->
<td colspan="7"> 

<table border="0" width="200" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>

</tr>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img style="border:1px solid #021a40;" src="Memberslogo-web-images/MP_Finance_220110_opt.gif" alt="Smiley face"  />
</td>

<td>
  <img style="border:1px solid #021a40;" src="Memberslogo-web-images/RMS_opt.jpeg" alt="Smiley face"  />
</td>
<td>
    <img style="border:1px solid #021a40;" src="Memberslogo-web-images/bbc-120x60_opt.jpeg" alt="Smiley face"  />
</td>
<td>
  <img style="border:1px solid #021a40;" src="Memberslogo-web-images/STATESTREET_opt.jpeg" alt="Smiley face"  />
</td> 
<td>
   <img style="border:1px solid #021a40;" src="Memberslogo-web-images/logo_opt.jpeg" alt="Smiley face"  />
</td>

</tr>
</table>
<!--Footer-->

<table>
<tr>
<td width="600" bgcolor="#828279" colspan="7" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px" align="center">
<p><span style="font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 23px;">
Pre-register today at <a style="text-decoration:none" href="">www.oursite.com</a> 
</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the image I want to insert in that column: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvQ7F.jpg

Answer (score 0):

table rows are not allowed to have content directly, you'll want to enclose the image within a `td` that has a column span of 2:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
-----INSERT IMAGE IN THE CENTER OF ONE COLUMN ROW-------
</td>
</tr>
```

In addition, take care with your comments. Here you have an unclosed comment that will likely make the display of the code following this block unpredictable:

```
<!--
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<!--forth one-->
```